# Floor a year to the decade in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I would like to floor a set of dates to the nearest decade, e.g:

```
1922 --> 1920,  
2099 --> 2090,
```

etc.

I was hoping I could do this in Lubridate, as in:

```
floor_date(1922, 'decade')
```

But I get:

```
Error in match.arg(unit) : 
  'arg' should be one of “second”, “minute”, “hour”, “day”, “week”, “month”, “year”
```

Is there any way to do this gracefully, perhaps avoiding a bunch of if-else statement to do the binning, and hopefully avoiding a bunch of `cut`s to do the grouping?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Floor a Year in R to nearest decade:**

Think of Modulus as a way to extract the rightmost digit and use it to subtract from the original year.  1998 - 8 = 1990

```
> 1992 - 1992 %% 10 
[1] 1990
> 1998 - 1998 %% 10
[1] 1990
```

**Ceiling a Year in R to nearest decade:**

Ceiling is exactly like floor, but add 10.

```
> 1998 - (1998 %% 10) + 10
[1] 2000
> 1992 - (1992 %% 10) + 10
[1] 2000
```

**Round a Year in R to nearest decade:**

Integer division converts your 1998 to 199.8, rounded to integer is 200, multiply that by 10 to get back to 2000.

```
> round(1992 / 10) * 10
[1] 1990
> round(1998 / 10) * 10
[1] 2000
```

### Same as above wrapped in an R function:

```
floor_decade    = function(value){ return(value - value %% 10) }
ceiling_decade  = function(value){ return(floor_decade(value)+10) }
round_to_decade = function(value){ return(round(value / 10) * 10) }
print(floor_decade(1992))
print(floor_decade(1998))
print(ceiling_decade(1992))
print(ceiling_decade(1998))
print(round_to_decade(1992))
print(round_to_decade(1998))
```

**which prints:**

```
# 1990
# 1990
# 2000
# 2000
# 1990
# 2000
```

Source:
https://rextester.com/AZL32693

**Another way to round to nearest decade:**
Neat trick with Rscript core function `round` such that the second argument digits can take a negative number.  See:  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/Round

```
round(1992, -1)    #prints 1990
round(1998, -1)    #prints 2000
```

Don't be shy on the duct tape with this dob, it's the only thing holding the unit together.

Comment: It's worth noting that `round` takes negative numbers for the second argument, so your example `round(1992 / 10) * 10` could be achieved with `round(1992, -1)` as well.

Answer (score 21):

You can just use some integer division here. Just see how many decades go into each number.

```
(c(1922, 2099) %/% 10) * 10
# [1] 1920 2090
```

Comment: Or similarly `x - (x %% 10)` .

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `floor_date()` for integers; it is for date or datetime objects. As already suggested in MrFlick's answer, you don't need lubridate to do integer calculation. If you do want to use lubridate, it can be done something like this:

```r
library(lubridate)

y <- ymd(c("2016-01-01", "2009-12-31"))
floor_date(y, years(10))
#> [1] "2010-01-01" "2000-01-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the floor function like this:

```
floor(1922 / 10) * 10
# [1] 1920
```

If you need to round and not floor:

```
round(1922, digits = -1)
# [1] 1920
```