# How to transform data in Column Date using cut function in R

Tags: r

I have a Release date column in my dataset and need to add a column Decade which supposed to have 4 levels of "1980s", "1990s", "2000s", "2010s".

1980s within 1980-01-01 to 1989-12-31

1990s within 1990-01-01 to 1999-12-31
etc.

Sample of Release Date Column

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
df$Decade <- cut(df$Release, c(1970,1980,1990,2000))
levels(df$Decade) <- c("1980s", "1990s", "2000s", "2010s")
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> Error in cut.Date(df$Release, 10 + c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000)) : 
>     invalid specification of 'breaks'

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352914/floor-a-year-to-the-decade-in-r

Answer (score 1):

For `"Date"` objects, you can't cut like that. I'm sure there's an R base version, but **lubridate** can make your life easier, if you don't care too much about the how or if you don't want to learn to do things from scratch.

```
library(lubridate)

Decade <- format(floor_date(Release, years(x=10)), "%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to convert `Release` into date, extract only first 3 characters of the year. So 199 for 1991 or 198 for 1987 and then add `"0s"` to get the decade.

```
df <- data.frame(Release = c('5/21/1980', '12/12/1980', '5/12/1991'))
df$Decade <- paste0(substring(as.Date(x, '%m/%d/%Y'), 1, 3), "0s")
df
#     Release Decade
#1  5/21/1980  1980s
#2 12/12/1980  1980s
#3  5/12/1991  1990s
```

Comment: OP said `Release` was already a date. But I like the addition of the "s" to the decade. ;)

Comment: @Edward Looking at the format of the dates in the screenshot, I don't think so.

Comment: @ Ronak. Looks like a screenshot from Excel. So it could be. :P

Comment: And, OP's error message said `Error in cut.Date(...`